# Meteor 0.8.0, Iron Router and Discover Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Meteor 0.8.0 is out with the new Blaze rendering, which is great... for the future.

At the present I can't run my Iron Router powered app: updated -> ran meteor -> white browser screen. I guess I'll roll back to 0.7.2. but that gives me a fuzzy feeling. Its like have a new computer with no internet connection. Is there any fix for these changes? At least for Iron Router?

Note Comment (although it was in the title):
I am learning meteor using the Discover Meteor book, it's a great book written by same author of Iron Router; I love it. However, if meteor changed that much am I wasting my time?

**Update**
@iAmME's solution works great! I solved it another way that also fixed iron-router-progress by modifying the smartpackage. Just wanted to post it if it helps anyone:

```
{
  "packages": {

      "blaze-layout": {},

      "iron-router":
      {
          "git": "https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git",
          "branch": "blaze-integration"
      },

      "iron-router-progress":
      {
          "git": "https://github.com/Multiply/iron-router-progress.git",
          "branch": "blaze-integration"
      }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just faced the same issue,

Did the following and works fine

It occurs **mostly** because of the iron-router package and few other packages which are using `spark` as dependency and first re-install the iron-router like below

```
meteor remove iron-router
rm -rf packages/iron-router
mrt update
mrt add iron-router
```

Just re-installing the iron-router  will update you to the new version and also it installs `blaze-Layout` automatically with the iron-router(which is the new templating system).

After updating iron-router,Even now if you are getting `spark` is not defined error,check which package is using `spark` and update those packages too.

Comment: Used `mrt add iron-router` in the last line. Works great otherwise.

Comment: Is this the proper way to remove and reinstall any mrt package?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your iron-router package. Check out the Iron Router github page https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router for information on what's new in their 0.7.0 release. It works for Meteor 0.8.0.