# Meteor 0.8 and iron-router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I just updated Meteor to 0.8. Now my app is crashing and I get 'spark is not defined'. I have read some articles stating that this can have something to do with the iron-router package. I'm clueless about what steps I should take to correct this.

Comment: I'm still getting this error and I've updated iron-router as per @iAmME's link. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because of iron-router package.
You need to update the package.

I just gave answer on this see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704773/meteor-0-8-0-iron-router-and-discover-meteor/22705209#22705209)

Comment: I also needed to update some other packages. But yes, this solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Old Spark rendering engine can be referenced by any of the packages you use in your application, so you get this error until all packages used are updated to Blaze, not only `iron-router` (this is why @Chris is still getting it).

Check which package is referencing Spark and check for updates.
Until `mrt update` doesn't automatically get results you can look for a `blaze` branch of the offending package and use it. For example the `accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` package has a blaze branch and you can already use it modifying your `smart.json`:

```
"accounts-ui-bootstrap-3": {
    "git": "https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3" ,
    "branch": "blaze"
},
```

As suggested in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/N1VB0_le3J4).

Comment: Already old info here :) `accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` has been updated: remove `git` and `branch` from `smart.json` and run `mrt update`.