# Issues with updating iron-router to work with blaze

Tags: iron-router

I have just updated meteor to blaze and followed the instructions to update iron-router to 0.7.0.

I'm getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'path' of undefined router.js:160

Any ideas on what may have gone wrong?

Comment: Try the solution from:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704773/meteor-0-8-0-iron-router-and-discover-meteor

Comment: I've already tried that - and the dev branch - no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was related to the event-hooks package I was using. Removed that and all seems fine.