# Meteor white screen after 0.8.0 update?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, localhost, preview

I just updated `Meteor` to version 0.8.0 and now when I try to run my app at `localhost:3000` it just shows a white screen. Does anybody know what is wrong here?

Comment: Have you looked at all the items to consider on the page they point out during the update? https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze

Comment: also, try opening the console in the browser looking for any errors. As Christian pointed out, the might be some porting to new apis required.

Comment: how do you open the console in the browser?

Comment: In Google Chrome, you can press Ctrl+Shift+J (Windows/Linux) or Cmd+Option+J (Mac). In Firefox, it's Ctrl+Shift+K (Windows/Linux) or Cmd+Option+K (Mac).

Comment: If you are using iron-router, you'll have to upgrade to the latest version that supports Meteor 0.8 and change {{yield}} to {{>yield}}.. prior to doing this, I also had a (mostly) white screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white screen is because of iron-router package.You need to update the package.

If you open up your browser and if the error is

```
spark is not defined
```

Then this is the solution for it.

Re-installing `iron-router` will solve your problem,follow these steps

```
meteor remove iron-router
rm -rf packages/iron-router
mrt update
mrt add iron-router
```

Just re-installing the iron-router will update you to the new version and also it installs blaze-Layout automatically with the iron-router(which is the new templating system)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704773/meteor-0-8-0-iron-router-and-discover-meteor/22705209#22705209).

Comment: Thanks iron-router was the issue. It works with no errors now