# Why am I not able to connect to meteor mongo on release blaze-rc1, says meteor not running?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am running meteor release blaze-rc1. The meteor server is running normally and I open up a new terminal tab in the same project directory and type:

```
$ meteor mongo
```

and I get

```
mongo: Meteor isn't running.

This command only works while Meteor is running your application
locally. Start your application first.
```

I have also tried

```
$ meteor --release blaze-rc1 mongo
```

and I get the same error message. What do I need to do in order to connect to meteor mongo?

Comment: `blaze-rc1` is outdated. Use the current stable release, 0.8.0, which includes Blaze.

Comment: Will 0.8.0 work with meteor-jade? I just tried to run 0.8.0 with my project and I get the error: While building package `accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown`: error: no such package: 'spark'. I checked and the package supports 0.8.0 I dono what the deal is

Comment: Looks like accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown actually does not work with 0.8.0 yet, seems like a known issue

Comment: If you are getting `error: no such package: 'spark'`,it is beacause of the iron-router,you need to update the iron-router package,check my answer on this here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704773/meteor-0-8-0-iron-router-and-discover-meteor/22705209#22705209

Comment: Are you sure, I think it is an actual issue with the account-ui-bootstrap-dropdown package. Looks like a fix is being worked on here: https://github.com/erobit/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown/issues/30#issuecomment-39025873 Have you gotten it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

I had to use the command

```
$ sudo meteor mongo
```

since I have to start my server using

```
$ sudo mrt
```

I guess sudo is necessary for me when using meteor. I noticed this happened after I upgraded.