# Blank page is coming after installing meteor 0.8.0, Iron Router

Tags: meteor

Meteor 0.8.0 is out with the new Blaze rendering, which is great... for the future.

At the present I can't run my Iron Router powered app: updated -> ran meteor -> white browser screen. Is there any fix for these changes? At least for Iron Router?

Followed the answer given in this link:[Meteor 0.8.0, Iron Router and Discover Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704773/meteor-0-8-0-iron-router-and-discover-meteor/22705209#22705209)

Still not working. Any pointers please as how one can proceed to prevent this white screen from coming. Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem might be that you have to replace `{{yield}}` in your layout templates with `{{> yield}}`. Are there any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: No, there are no errors. Previously errors that coming were regarding {{{}}} i.e triple tags only. But after changing it to {{}}. No error is coming. I have seen the packages installed by "meteor list --using commnand" and app contains standard-app-packages, 
bootstrap, 
router, 
accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown, 
accounts-password, 
spin, 
paginated-subscription, 
email, 
insecure, 
iron-router, 
What can be done to make app perfectly running

Comment: Can you please tell me what can be done to prevent the page from coming blank.

Comment: Blaze has some backwards-incompatible API changes, look at [this wiki page](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze). I can't tell what the problem is without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Did Blaze-layout get added to your smart.lock?  Is this app public somewhere like Github?

**Update**

After looking at your code, it looks like you are using *router*, not *iron-router*!  `mrt remove router` and `mrt add iron-router` to see if that works for you.

Comment: No, It is showing all the packages like "router": {}, "paginated-subscription":{}, "spin":{}, "iron-router":{}, "accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown":{}. Here is the link for th github "https://github.com/pszjmb1/grumblebutton"